# Emberjs sort content by date using sortProperties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to use Emberjs  **sortProperties** to sort content by date in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmtpX/2/)**. My model has a **startTime** property which I tried to sort by but it didn't work. I then created a computed property called **todayEvent** in the controller which returns events that match the passed in date and I tried to sort that but it also didn't work. All I am trying to do  is list events occurring on same day but in such a way that time of the day in chich event occurs is sorted in ascending order for example, an event occurring by  **10am** should be listed before those occurring by say **12pm**.

This is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmtpX/2/)**

The model:

```
App.TimeSlot = DS.Model.extend( {
  startTime: DS.attr('date'),
  endTime: DS.attr('date'),
  allDay: DS.attr('boolean'),
  soldOut: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

The controller

```
App.TimeSlotController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
 content: [ ],

 sortProperties: ['todayEvent'],
 sortAscending: true,

 day: Ember.A(['2013-10-25']),

 todayEvent: function(){
  self = this;
  u = self.get('content'); 
  console.log('u', u);
  kl =  u.filter(function(availableSlot) {
   console.log ('a', availableSlot.get('startTime') );

 return (moment(availableSlot.get('startTime')).format("YYYY-MM-DD") ==  self.get('day').toString() );
  }); 

   return kl;  
 }.property('day', 'content@each'),


});
```

The fixtureAdapter

```
App.TimeSlot.FIXTURES = [

  {
    id: 3,
    startTime: moment.utc('2013-10-25T12:30:00+01:00',"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" ),    
    allDay: true
  },

 {
   id: 4,
   startTime: moment.utc('2013-10-25T10:10:00+01:00',"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" ),    
   allDay: true
},

 {
  id: 5,    
  startTime: moment.utc('2013-10-23 00:00 +01:00', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),    
  allDay: true
 }
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve it @edu but thanks for trying to help. You can see a working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNdPJ/2/)**.

There are two approaches and both use **Ember.computed.sort**:

```
 sortedTime: Ember.computed.sort('todayEvent',       function(a, b){

    if (
      moment(Ember.get(a, 'startTime') ) >  moment(Ember.get(b, 'startTime') ) 
    ){

   //returns morning timings before afternoon timings
   //api doc says return 1 when 'a' should come after 'b'
   //http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_sort

   return 1;

   } else if ( 
      moment(Ember.get(a, 'startTime') ) <   moment(Ember.get(b, 'startTime') ) 
   )
   {
    //returns afternoon timings before morning timings
   //api docs says return -1, when 'a' should come before 'b'
    return -1;
   }
     return 0;

  })
```

The second approach

```
  //adapted from http://jsbin.com/OjoXOqE/9/edit

  sortedContent: Ember.computed.sort('content.@each.startTime', function(a, b){

    //the this keyword does not work here, 
    //throws "Object #<Object> has no method 'get'"
    //so we use the Ember keyword to get it working

   var ap = moment(Ember.get(a, 'startTime')),
       bp = moment(Ember.get(b, 'startTime'))

  //we return morning before afternoon times 
    if(ap !== bp) {
      return ap - bp;
    }

  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [.sortBy()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_sortBy) to sort an array of objects containing dates.

In your model:

```
fooDate: DS.attr('date')
```

In your component/controller/route:

```
dateSortedFoos: function() {
  return this.get('model.foos').sortBy('fooDate');
}.property('model.foos.@each'),
```

No need to iterate through or to use Moment JS.

Works with dates in this format `"2015-09-11T08:15:00+10:00"`.

For reference: I'm using Ember 1.13.10 and Ember Data 1.13.9.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply override `sortFunction` on your `ArrayController`. See [Sort Function](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_sortFunction)

```
App.TimeSlotController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['startTime'],
  sortAscending: true,
  sortFunction: function (dateX, dateY) {
    return Ember.compare(dateX.getTime(), dateY.getTime());
  }
```

Comment: This would work except that the date values are stored as strings and not objects.

Answer (score 1):

The sorted content of the controller lives in the property named arrangedContent, so inside controller you should call

```
this.get('arrangedContent')
```

or in handlebars

```
{{#each arrangedContent}}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Previously or before posting the question, in handlebars I had tried **{{#each arrangedContent}}** and it did not sort the date. So this time, I tried your first suggestion by using **self.get('arrangedContent')** instead of **self.get('content')** from within the **todayEvent property** but it did not work. Here is the **[jsfiddle incorporating both of your suggestions](http://jsfiddle.net/CmtpX/3/)**

Comment: todayEvent should be a property of each item in the content of the arrayController, not a property of the arrayController, like it's now in your code

Comment: Sorry do you mind explaining what you mean by todayEvent should be a property of each item in the content of the arrayController. Are you saying todayEvent should be moved to an itemcontroller, as this is how I understand your comment and will try to do that now. thanks.

Comment: Yes should be moved to an itemController

Comment: Thanks. I moved it to an **[itemController in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNdPJ/)** and it is still not sorting by date.

Comment: You are returning an array for the todayEvent prperty `kl =  u.filter` I don't know if it should be a number or string in order to the sort do it's job

Comment: Ok thanks for helping. I will keeping experiment to see if something will work.

Comment: If I use **sortProperties: ['id']**, with **sortAscending: false**, it lists the events that occur in the morning before those occurring in the afternoon. But this won't work well when you have a 100 or 1000  events with different **id** and **startTime**. There will be no way to guarantee that morning events will be listed before those in the afternoon and those occurring in the afternoon listed before those occurring at evening..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I figured out that I will post a new, more 'up-to-date' answer.

To sort an iterable by dates, you can use Ember.computed.sort in this way:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
//...stuff
eventsArray: [
  {eventName: 'Event One', date: dateObject1},
  {eventName: 'Event One', date: dateObject2},
],
eventsArraySortDefinition: ['date:ascending],
sortedStuff: Ember.computed.sort('eventsArray', 'eventsArraySortDefinition'),
//...stuff
})
```

It is worth noting, that when you define a model property with type 'date' ( `date: DS.attr('date')` ) than a date in a string format like '2016-10-17' will be nicely converted and stored in the model as a `Date` object. During sorting, the date will be explicitly converted to a timestamp, so you don't need to do any convertion yourself.

Comment: Greg, your code worked, but need to use short 'asc' or 'desc' in ['date:ascending'].