# Sorting date not works as per expected

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I am trying to sort the `amount` and `date`. But the `date` function not works properly. what is the correct way with ember sorting method?

my code :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  sortingDate: ['date-of-purchase:desc'],
    sortingAmout: ['amount:desc'],
    sortByAmountSpent:Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortingDate'),
    sortByDateOfPurchase:Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortingAmout')
  ,actions:{
    sortByAmount:function(){
      this.set("model", this.get('sortByAmountSpent'));
    },
    sortByDate:function(){
       this.set("model", this.get('sortByDateOfPurchase'));
    },
  }
});
```

here is my try :

[Twiddle-link](https://ember-twiddle.com/73acd0ff6530dbe5a5725876f120fb59?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) You mixed up the sorting between date and amount

```
sortByAmountSpent:Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortingDate'),
sortByDateOfPurchase:Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortingAmout')
```

2) your model data is all Strings, therefore the sorting is lexicographically (e.g. 8 is considered greater than 77). You sort by amount does not work, either. You have to have the date-property set up as correct Date, then you can use solutions like this: [Emberjs sort content by date using sortProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903389/emberjs-sort-content-by-date-using-sortproperties#19915469) to sort these correctly.

Comment: So how to parse my numbers and sort it out? any help

Comment: i do not know how you populate your model-array in your "real" application. In the twiddle i would just write these values https://ember-twiddle.com/73acd0ff6530dbe5a5725876f120fb59?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C